# $F(x) = |x-1|+|x^2-2x|$ domain $[0,2]$ max and min?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

When $0<x<1 $ the critical point is $x=0.5$ and $y = 5/4$
When $1<x<2 $ the critical point is $x=1.5$ and $y = 5/4$

$F(0) = 1$ and $F(2) = 1$
Do I have to include the boundaries in the domain?
If it written $[0,2]$ do I have to test $0$ and $2$? Is the max $5/4$ and the min $1$?

Comment: Yes, the square brackets $[0,2]$ mean you include $0$ and $2$ in your domain. (If the domain was not a closed interval, the min and max might not exist.) You also need to explicitly test $x=1$, because the function isn't differentiable here, so you can't proceed by use of critical points. You indeed have the right max and min on the given domain.

Comment: How to explicitly test x=1?

Comment: To explicitly test the value at $x = 1$, substitute $1$ for $x$.